# Visual Studio/Xamarin fails to connect to mac with Xamarin Mac Agent despite working in the past

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, remote-debugging

So when I first installed it Xamarin Mac Agent connected to my mac just fine.  I hadn't changed any settings, but when I came back into work it had suddenly stopped working.  Here's the output from the console:

```
Starting connection to Mac 192.168.1.113...
Installing Broker 4.2.2.6...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (544/5404 KB) 10%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (1088/5404 KB) 20%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (1632/5404 KB) 30%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (2176/5404 KB) 40%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (2704/5404 KB) 50%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (3248/5404 KB) 60%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (3792/5404 KB) 70%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (4336/5404 KB) 80%...
Uploading Broker 4.2.2.6 (4880/5404 KB) 90%...
Uploaded Broker 4.2.2.6 100%
Unable to install the Broker
Couldn't connect to 192.168.1.113. Please try again.
Disconnected from Mac 192.168.1.113 (192.168.1.113)
```

I have both machines on the same update channel.  Tried switching from stable to beta and no luck.  Both are updated to the latest version, my remote login settings on my mac are correct, and I've tried doing both all users and specifically putting my account under allowed users.  Nothing seems to be working and I can find very few people having this exact problem with the broker being unable to install.

Comment: Have you looked at this troubleshooting guide?https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

Comment: @PrashantC Oh yeah I have.  Done just about every suggested solution on it.  No luck.

Comment: If this is still a problem, please post the [logs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Log_File_Location) and full version info for both Xamarin Studio Mac: Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details > Copy Information [button]
& Visual Studio: Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]

Comment: @ashley Ended up just changing the update channel to alpha and it fixed it.  Had already tried switching to beta and didn't work but alpha did the trick.  Thanks for the help, though!